# How to apply a series of iterators to data?

Tags: rust, iterator

I'm tinkering with Rust by building some basic genetics functionality, e.g. read a file with a DNA sequence, transcribe it to RNA, translate it to an amino acid sequence, etc.

I'd like each of these transformations to accept and return iterators. That way I can string them together (like `dna.transcribe().traslate()...`) and only collect when necessary, so the compiler can optimize the entire chain of transormations. I'm a data scientist coming from Scala/Spark, so this pattern makes a lot of sense, but I'm not sure how to implement it Rust.

I've read [this article about returning iterators](https://depth-first.com/articles/2020/06/22/returning-rust-iterators/) but the final solution seems to be to use trait objects (with possibly large performance impact), or to hand roll iterators with associated structs (which allows me to return an iterator, yes, but I don't see how it would allow me to write a transformation that also *accepts* an iterator).

Any general architectural advice here?

(FYI, my code so far is [available here](https://github.com/cyniphile/rosalind/blob/use-enums/bio-lib/src/lib.rs), but I feel like I'm not using Rust idiomatically because a. still can't quite get it to compile b. this pattern of lazily chaining operations has led to unexpectedly complex and messy code that only works on Rust nightly.)

Comment: How do you know that boxing the iterator is a performance problem - have you actually measured? People tend to say that returning a boxed iterator hampers performance, and it's true that it can prevent some optimizations from happening (such as aggressive inlining), but keep in mind that the dreaded "dynamic dispatch" is literally one pointer read + jump. (It's not a dict lookup like in Python.) If you do anything substantial with each item, you'll never notice the dispatches. See that you're not investing a large effort in solving a non-problem - the only way to be sure is to measure.

Comment: @user4815162342 True. That said the whole reason I'm using iterators is for performance (as mentioned in the first paragraph of my question). I wanted to see if chaining iterators together was better than chaining functions that accept and return vectors (with a `collect` in each function). So far the iterator pattern is slower, even without dynamic dispatch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterator adaptors are meant to do operations which can't easily be expressed otherwise. Your two examples, `.translate()`, and `.transcribe()`, given your explanation of them, could be simplified to the following:

```rs
dna
    .map(|x| x.translate())
    .map(|x| x.transcribe())

// or

dna
    .map(|x| x.translate().transcribe())
```

However, if you are intent on designing your own iterator, the following should work:

```rs
struct Transcriber<I: Iterator<Item = Dna>> {
    inner: I
}

impl<I: Iterator<Item = Dna>> Iterator for Transcriber<I> {
    type Item = TranscribedDna;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.next().map(|x| x.transcribe())
    }
}

// Extension trait to add the `.transcribe` method to existing iterators
trait TranscribeIteratorExt: Iterator<Item = Dna> {
    fn transcribe(self) -> Transcriber<Self>;
}

impl<I: Iterator<Item = Dna>> TranscriberIteratorExt for I {
    fn transcribe(self) -> Transcriber<Self> {
        Transcriber { inner: self }
    }
}
```

Then you can use

```
dna
    .transcribe() // yields TranscribedDna
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The first solution doesn't quite work because (as you might remember from bio) three rna items translate to an amino acid, so you'd have to do `rna.chunks(3).map(translate)`. So basically I want a sugar where I can call `rna.translate()` instead, and more generally encapsulate a transformation of any kind in a funtion `iter -> iter`. The hand-rolled iterator you shared makes sense (again thanks!) and would work, but seems like a lot of code and work just for that sugar. I guess that's the only way in rust?

Comment: Well, then the most concise way of expressing this is indeed using `.chunks()`. Such extra sugar need only be written once in a file and stowed away, all important functionality on iterators can be imported by importing the iterator extension trait. But then again, hand rolled iterators let you deal with edge cases more explicitly (it reads cleaner than inline in dense iterator code), such as what happens when you don't get 3 RNA items due to a logical bug.